# Can Lighttpd set "connection.kbytes-per-second" depends on the hour of the day? Such as peak and offpeak

Tags: lighttpd

Is it possible to set "connection.kbytes-per-second" depends on the hour of the day in Lighttpd?

Such as between 7pm-11pm limit it to 250kb/s, 1am-5am limit it to 500kb/s etc?

Thanks!

Comment: After a little experimenting something dirty can be hacked together using mod_magnet. It could be clean, but I couldn't figure out how to set connection speed inside the lua code, so it involves setting something like the url or query string and restarting the request and catching it in some other rule. I'll try to post code later.

Comment: @Macattack thanks! waiting for your reply! It will be a useful function/feature for many webmasters indeed!

Answer (score 1):

Sorry for the delay, my answer - the lua script:

```
-- If we don't find our "superSecretString" in the request uri, then
if string.find(lighty.env["request.uri"], "superSecretString") == nil then
    local hour = os.date("%H")
    -- Account for whether or not there are already query variables
    if string.find(lighty.env["request.uri"], "?") == nil then
        lighty.env["request.uri"] = lighty.env["request.uri"] .. "?superSecretString=" .. hour
    else
        lighty.env["request.uri"] = lighty.env["request.uri"] .. "&superSecretString=" .. hour
    end
    -- Restart the request, the script will run again, but return nil.
    return lighty.RESTART_REQUEST 
end

-- Continue request, the above if already would have ran.
return nil
```

and the configuration file:

```
server.modules( ..., mod_magnet, ...)

# Match hours 00 through 19
$HTTP["querystring"] =~ ".*superSecretString=[0,1][0-9]" {
    connection.kbytes-per-second = 200
}
# Match 20 through 23
$HTTP["querystring"] =~ ".*superSecretString=2[0-3]" {
    connection.kbytes-per-second = 100
}

magnet.attract-raw-url-to = ( "<path to lua script file>" )
```

In case it isn't obvious, if anyone knew your "superSecretString" they'd be able to short circuit this, but it never leaves the server.

I feel like it should be possible to set the connection speed from inside the lua script, but I couldn't figure out how to.

Hope this helps.

Comment: is it possible to set connection.kbytes-per-second without passing query string method?

Comment: The best way would be to set the connection speed inside the lua script, but I don't know how to do that. Otherwise, you can store the time in anything that's modifiable inside the script, and accessible from regular config rules. So it could be part of the url, or any of a number of things.